# Python - "Unlist" a nested element in a list

Tags: python, list

Is there any quick ways to untangle elements in a list?
For example:
Given

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,2],2,1,3]
```

We'll have:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,2,2,1,3]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension after casting any non-list values as lists:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,2],2,1,3]
new_l = [i for b in map(lambda x:[x] if not isinstance(x, list) else x, l) for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

Edit: for nested levels, you can use recursion with a generator expression:

```
def flatten(d):
 v = [[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else flatten(i) for i in d]
 return [i for b in v for i in b]
```

print(flatten(l)
Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: What if there are more levels of nesting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertool.chain` for this:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [[1,2,3],[4,2],2,1,3]

res = list(chain.from_iterable(i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in lst))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```